# Reliable timeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, countdown

We're implementing an AngularJS application which displays questions to a user and counts the number of correct answers. The test is strictly limited to 20 minutes. But there are a few tricky requirements:

#### Accuracy

The error for 20 minutes timeout must not exceed 2 seconds, even for not-so-fast devices like Android 2.3 tablets or iPad 2.

#### Local time modifications tolerance

The result of the timeout must not be affected by changing the computer's local time. We cannot kick the user out as a cheater when such a change is detected: it might as well be caused by an honest NTP update.

#### Progress tracking

The user must be reminded with remaining time by a constantly ticking countdown which should not accumulate error if the UI is lagging.

-

I've tried a few approaches which didn't work:

- `windows.performance.now`: hardly implemented anywhere (Mobile Safari is a requirement)
- Server pingbacks: constant internet connection must not be required

Is it possible to implement all requirements at once?

Comment: Use a setInterval to a much shorter span and check the `new Date()` value

Comment: No. You need a connection to the server to ensure the user doesn't tamper with their timer.

Comment: To enforce any time limits, you will need to do it on the server side anyway.

Comment: The way I read the requirements, they have to allow the user to tamper with the timer since it could be a local time-change outside of the user's control.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval) for this.

Check out the bottom example on that page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need some backend, that does the counting for you. If you manage your counter completely on clientside, reloading the site will kill the counter.

You can sync the counter initially with the backend and count down on clientside. The 20 min expire should be send by backend, maybe using Server-sent events or nodejs.

By moving the real counter into the backend, you will remove any possible impact for cheating or lagging on clientside.

To make sure, that the counter is right, you could synchronize it in a intervall with the backend.

Comment: Loosing timer data when reloading the page could be countered, manipulating the data cannot.

Comment: you can actually open the console and type `alert(1)` this will stop the current threads from working, including all `$scope.$apply`

Comment: The backend double-checks the time limit. As for sending the event from the server, I'm afraid it won't work. Consider the following case: if the client timer lags, the incoming server event will terminate testing when UI says there's still time left. The user experience will be extremely frustrating.

Comment: maybe only give the user hints in a intervall like 10, 5, 2 minutes before time is over, all server sent. Instead placing this timer, that counts down like a bomb and sets up pressure on the user.